# the result from my custom each method is producing a nil in ruby

Tags: ruby

```
 def custom_each(array)
  index = 0 
  while index < array.length
    yield array[index]
    index += 1
  end
end 

ages = [12, 45, 67, 89]
p custom_each(ages) { |num| num * 2 }
```

Any ideas? im a total beginner?

im doing this course https://www.rubyguides.com/2018/10/ruby-map-method/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default last executed expression in the function will returned. The result of the block execution `yield array[index]` haven't saved and returned from the function `custom_each`. That's why it returns nil always

Try the below:

```
def custom_each(array)
  index = 0
  result = []

  while index < array.length
    result << yield(array[index]) # Saves the result of block execution in an array
    index += 1
  end
  result # Returns the result
end

ages = [12, 45, 67, 89]
p custom_each(ages) { |num| num * 2 }
```

Output:

```
[24, 90, 134, 178]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `custom_each` method works just fine. All you have to do is move `p` *inside* the block:

```
# built-in each
ages.each { |num| p num * 2 }

# your custom_each
custom_each(ages) { |num| p num * 2 }
```

Output:

```
24
90
134
178
```

Note that the original `Array#each` doesn't return an altered array  either. It returns an enumerator or the original array:

```
[12, 45, 67, 89].each
#=> #<Enumerator: [12, 45, 67, 89]:each>

[12, 45, 67, 89].each { |num| num * 2 }
#=> [12, 45, 67, 89]
```